# What is the difference in how $\mathrm{R}^2$ and $\mathrm{R}$ values are interpreted?

Tags: r, regression, correlation, model

In statistics, there is the $\mathrm{R}$ value for the product moment correlation coefficient and the $\mathrm{R}^2$ value for the coefficient of determination.

In both cases they are described as a scale of correlation, where $0$ is no correlation and $1$ is perfect correlation. However, for a given data set these values are different - for example when $\mathrm{R}=0.8$ the $\mathrm{R}^2=0.64$. How can this be so?

Another layer of confusion is that for the $\mathrm{R}^2$ value, it is said that the value represents the proportion of change in $y$ caused by changes in $x$. For instance, an $\mathrm{R}^2$ value of 0.7 means that 70% of the change in the dependent variable is explained by changes in the independent variable. Is this also true of the $\mathrm{R}$ value? Why or why not?

Comment: Just because $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2$ are equal when $x=0$ and $x=1$ is not a reason to believe they represent the same thing

Answer (score 4):

The *linear correlation coefficient*, also referred to as *Pearson product moment correlation coefficient* and denoted by $r$,  measures the strength and the direction of a linear relationship between two variables $X$ and $Y$.
 The value of $r$ lies in the range **$-1\le r \le 1$**. Here numeric value of $r$ tells the strength and sign tells the direction of relationship between the two variables. An $r$ value of exactly $+1$ indicates a perfectly positive fit *i.e.*, it indicates a relationship between $X$ and $Y$ variables such that as values for $X$ increase (decrease), values for  $Y$ also increase (decrease). A negative $r$ value means that if $X$ increases, then $Y$ decreases or vice versa.
 A correlation greater than $0.8$ is generally described as strong, whereas a correlation less than $0.5$ is generally described as weak. Notice that the $r$ value is does not tell anything about the slope of the regression line. The formula for computing $r$ is:
$$ r = r_{xy} = \frac {\sum x_iy_i - n\bar {x} \bar{y}}{\sqrt {\sum x_i^2 - n \bar x^2} \sqrt {\sum y_i^2 - n \bar y^2}} $$

$R^2$, referred to as the *coefficient of determination*, and obtained by squaring the $r$ value, *i.e.*, $R^2 = r^2$, is an effect size parameter of linear equation **$\hat{y_i} = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_i + \epsilon_i $**. The following equation computes $R^2$:
$$R^2 = \frac {\sum(\hat y_i - \bar y)^2} {{\sum(\hat y_i - \bar y)^2} + {\sum(y_{i} - \hat y_i})^2}$$
$$= \frac{Explained \ Sum \ of \ Squares \ (ESS)}{ESS \ + Residual \ Sum \ of \ Squares \ (RSS) }$$
$$ = \frac{Variability \ explained \ by \ model}{Total \ variability}$$
$$ = Proportion \ of \ variability \ explained \ by \ model $$
$R^2$ value is useful in that it gives the proportion of the variance (fluctuation) of one variable that is predictable from the other variable. It is a measure that allows us to determine how certain one can be in making predictions from a certain model/graph. The *coefficient of determination* is the ratio of the explained variation to the total variation. So an $R^2$ value of $0.64$ indicates that $64\%$ of the changes in $Y$ is due the changes in $X$; the remaining $36\%$ changes in $Y$ cannot be explained by the changes in $X$ or the model. $R^2$ value is limited within **$0\le R^2 \le 1$**.